# Restart a thread - This is over way my head

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a thread that shows stopwatch like decreasing time. This thread counts 1 minute. In this one minute, the user has to answer a question. If the user answers the question before the completion of one minute, then next question is shown to him and the thread is reset to count 1 minute.

The Problem I am facing is, when I make a call to reStartTimeKeeper(), then the timer restarts but it starts to count faster. And every subsequent call to it, further increases the speed of the counter. I mean, after 1st call to reStartTimeKeeper(), my timmer counts 60 secs in 30 secs (approx) and after 2nd call to reStartTimeKeeper(), my timmer counts 60 secs in 15 secs (approx). and so on.

The reason for this is when I set Question_Time=-1 in reStartTimeKeeper(), the 1st instance of the Thread is paused. It continually executes the while loop, as if it is waiting for the condition in the while() to become true.

When I try to initiate the second instance of the thread, I set Question_Time=60. This initiates the new instance of the thread. And doing this also activates the dormant 1st instance which was waiting for while condition to become true.

I just want 1 instance of my thread at any instance of time. I made it a static variable. Doing this also has no effect.

```
        int Question_Time=-1;
        static Thread timeKeeper;
        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        void Start_TimeKeeper()
        {
                Question_Time=60;
            timeKeeper = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (Question_Time!=-1) 
                    {
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() 
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                Question_Time--;
                                UpdateUI();
                            }
                        });

                        try 
                        {
                            Thread.sleep((1000));
                        } 
                        catch (InterruptedException e) 
                        {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            timeKeeper.start();
        }

void reStartTimeKeeper()
{
Question_Time=0;
while(Question_Time==-1);
Start_TimeKeeper();
}
```

If some one can me sync this flow it would be great!
And if you find any thing silly or some suggestion for improvement, it would be most welcome.
Thanks!

When I try to initiate the second instance of the thread, I set Question_Time=60. This initiates the new instance of the thread. And doing this also activates the dormant 1st instance which was waiting for while condition to become true. I want to comletely kill the first instance of the thread, and when it is killed, I want to safely re start the new Instance.

Comment: whya not using CountDownTimer?

Comment: I just have some spare time, I thought, doing it with threads would help me understand Threads better. CountDownTimer can be the my last resort! Any suggestions with this one??

Comment: Yes this may be a good approach, but Timers are more accurate and You have the simple solution to stop them with cancel().

Comment: The right solution is to use timers, but the question is about "help with threads" so ... Question time is 20.  The while loop is entered because it is not -1.  The other thread sets it to -1.  This thread sets it to -2.  The while loop continues because it is not -1.  This is a race condition - read up on those!

Comment: Alternatively, and much more likely: Question time is 20. While loop entered. Time set to -1 to stop it.  Time set to 60 again before it stops.  While loop continues.  Try looking up "Synchronized" and "AtomicBoolean.compareAndSet" as possible approaches to fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Start_TimeKeeper();` it will start an other thread without stoping the first one. So your both threads decreases the time. That is why it is counting faster.

Instead of creating a new thread every time, can't you just check if old thread is finished, if so, start a new one otherwise just reset the `Question_Timeint`.

---

```
class TimeKeeper extends Thread {

    private volatile boolean run = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        run=true;//run while run=true
        while (run) {
            if (Question_Time >= 0) {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Question_Time--;
                        UpdateUI();
                    }
                });
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(Question_Time >= 0 ? 1000 : 5000);//loop with longer delays if question time is below zero
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void finish() {
        run = false;
    }

}
```

Use this TimeKeeper class. Start it once, use every time, reset variable to restart.

Comment: Actually, no. He does make an attempt to stop the old thread via setting the timer to -1. Problem is that's a bad mechanism to do it.

Comment: My thread works on this variable : Question_Time. In reStartTimeKeeper(), I have made this variable 0, and I am waiting for my current thread to make it -1(Termination condition for the loop), its only there after, that I restart my thread. So by doing this I assume, I have finished the old thread.

Comment: You need to call `Thread.join()` to be sure, your old thread finished. But this is really a bad way to do it.

Comment: @Ordous can you please suggest a way to completely kill my first instance, so that I can safely start the second instance. Its my first hit at implementing Threading, so plz bear with me.

Comment: @Eu.Dr. e better approach is starting the thread once and use it by resetting the QuestionTime variable. Check my edit.

Comment: If I want to restart the thread, I will have to set run = true; and also reset QuestionTime = 60. Just doing this should reStart my second instance of counter? If yes. Then it means that the thread is still toiling uselessly in background, and checking the while condition, whereas I think once the while condition becomes false, All the resources allocated to it should be re-claimed by the system. And thus, to re initiate a thread, we should have to SPAWN a new thread. But I do not think this is how it works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Two main problems (apart from conceptual problems about the whole approach):

1. No synchronization. As Andy posted in his comment:

   1. Reset time keeper is called
   2. Reset sets the time to 0
   3. Time keeper sets the time to -1
   4. Reset enters the loop
   5. Reset sets the time to 60
   6. Time keeper enters next loop iteration
   7. Reset creates secondary time keeper
   8. PROFIT! (two parallel time keepers).
2. Memory visibility. The time is a non-volatile primitive. There is no guarantee that the `while` in your thread actually sees the latest value of time left.

Both of these can be alleviated by using an atomic variable for your time left (And a bit of thought on how exactly you use it, just calling `.get()` to a local var is not going to work).

An even better approach is *not to spawn so many threads*. Use a single time thread that loops indefinitely and when a boolean flag is set - decrements the counter.

If you still want to spawn threads and kill them properly - this should help: [Stop, interrupt, suspend and resume a java thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)